# Error loading(insert) images in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, ckeditor

When I write my functions as below, you can see that there is a record as seen in the image. Where exactly is the problem?

[image]

Which is the function that records like in the image?

The image saves as I want, but it saves to the database as in the image.

I did according to the answer in [How to use custom upload adapter on ASP.Net Core - CKEDITOR 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446497/how-to-use-custom-upload-adapter-on-asp-net-core-ckeditor-5) but I can't solve the problem

!!How can I give this.url to src?

```
class MyUploadAdapter
{
 constructor(loader) {
 // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
      this.loader = loader;
      this.urls = '/tr/UnitType/DocUploadImage';
         }
        // Starts the upload process.
         upload() {
     return this.loader.file.then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         this._initRequest();
         this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
         this._sendRequest(file);
                }));
            }
 // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
    if (this.xhr) {
    this.xhr.abort();
    }
    }

    _initRequest() {
    const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', this.urls, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }
  // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
     const xhr = this.xhr;
     const loader = this.loader;
     const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;

     xhr.addEventListener('error', () => reject(genericErrorText));
     xhr.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
     xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
     const response = xhr.response;

   if (!response || response.error) {
     return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText);
     }
    resolve({
         default: response.urls
              });
               });

        if (xhr.upload) {
           xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
           loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
           loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
        }
        });
                }
            }

            // Prepares the data and sends the request.
            _sendRequest(file) {
                // Prepare the form data.
                const data = new FormData();

                data.append('upload', file);

                this.xhr.send(data);
            }
        }

        function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
            editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
                return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
            };
        }
```

```
        public async Task<JsonResult> DocUploadImage()
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
                var webRootPath = config["AppSettings:urunResimPath"].ToString();

                var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "assets");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, "rich-text");
                var urls = new List<string>();

                //If folder of new key is not exist, create the folder.
                if (!Directory.Exists(filePath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);

                foreach (var contentFile in Request.Form.Files)
                {
                    if (contentFile != null && contentFile.Length > 0)
                    {
                        await contentFile.CopyToAsync(new FileStream($"{filePath}\\{contentFile.FileName}", FileMode.Create));
                        urls.Add($"{HttpContext.Request.Host}/rich-text/{contentFile.FileName}");
                    }
                }

                return Json(urls);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { error = new { message = e.Message } });
            }
        }
```

Comment: !!How can I give this.url to src?